# Query explanation

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a query similar to the following,

```
select * from T1 where abc in (select distinct abc from T2);
```

the scenario is that there is **NO field named abc in table T2**, so the inner query goes invalid, but still the whole query returns the output.

What is the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: By itself the inner query is invalid. As a correlated subquery, it is valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no column `abc` in `t2`, the reference to `abc` in the subquery will be resolved by looking for a column `abc` in `t1`.  So the query ends up being

```
select * 
  from T1 
 where t1.abc in (select distinct t1.abc 
                    from T2);
```

which is always true (assuming that `T2` has at least 1 row and `t1.abc` is not NULL.

This is one of the many reasons that you should always qualify your column references.  That way, you'll get a syntax error rather than getting an unexpected reference to a different table.

Answer (score 0):

abc from T1 is visible to the subquery and can be listed in any expression on the table T2.

So for each row in T2, the value of abc for the current row in T1 will be returned.

Because you have distinct, the subselect will return just one row.

What is in effect 'abc in (abc)' will therefore always be true and hence you've effectively written

```
select * from T1;
```